# pdfMake: Use System Fonts

Tags: javascript, pdf-generation

I am using the [pdfMake](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake)-library to generate PDF documents on the client side in one of my applications. My main problem when using the library is that it relies on having available fonts in a virtual file system. The fonts are therefore sent to the client in a JavaScript file called [vfs_fonts.js](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/blob/master/build/vfs_fonts.js) and are then loaded into the virtual file system and later embedded in the resulting PDF-file (of course only the used character subset of the whole font).

With the default settings the library uses the Roboto font and therefore sends a little more than 800kb only for the fonts. My main intuition here is:

**Why doesn't it use the system fonts and as a result saves traffic?**

**Is there a workaround to make it use system fonts?**

My current approach to reduce the traffic is to remove the font styles from the vfs_fonts.js that aren't used in the documents that I create. E.g. I remove the italic, bold style and italic/bold style when only using regular styles. With this method I was at least able to reduce the size of the font file by 3/4.

Comment: Did you figure anything out?

Comment: No, still on it. I guess I will also file a feature request on github during the next days.

Comment: Hi, currently it's impossible with the underlying library (pdfkit). Unfortunately we'll have to put it off

Comment: Thank you very much for that information. Lets hope that one day it will be possible with pdfkit :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am also using PDFmake and I have encountered a similar problem.

You have to add any new source through a corresponding key, like this:

```
pdfmake.fonts = {
   'Roboto' : {
      normal: 'Roboto-Regular.ttf',
      bold: 'Roboto-Medium.ttf',
      italics: 'Roboto-Italic.ttf',
      bolditalics: 'Roboto-Italic.ttf'
   },

   'OpenSans' : {
      normal: 'OpenSans-Regular.ttf',
      bold: 'OpenSans-Medium.ttf',
      italics: 'OpenSans-Italic.ttf',
      bolditalics: 'OpenSans-Italic.ttf'
   }

}
```

Then in the PDF content you must add the "font" that you are going to use.

```
{
   stack : [
      { 
         text : 'this is a test text',
         font  : 'OpenSans',
         italic : true
      }, { 
         text : 'this is another test text',
         font : 'Roboto',
         bold : true
      }  
   ]
}
```

I hope you find it a good solution for people who are looking for a solution.

[Source here.](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/issues/673#issuecomment-240907589) Thanks to Daniel Arbiol ([Darbiol](https://github.com/Darbiol)).

Answer (score 2):

As bartekp, the main maintainer of pdfMake pointed out, this feature is currently not achievable because of limitations of the underlying pdfkit library.

Therefore in order to reduce the size of the font file the best option at this moment might be removing unused fonts and using gzip compression for your webserver.

Answer (score 0):

PDFKit now supports [standard fonts](https://github.com/devongovett/pdfkit/blob/f5b4f675c1171c5336343a35dfa0c9b7e5afbebd/docs/text.coffee.md#fonts).

```
# Using a standard PDF font
doc.font('Times-Roman')
   .text('Hello from Times Roman!')
   .moveDown(0.5)
```

See also this [live example](http://pdfkit.org/demo/browser.html).

Answer (score -1):

there are some efforts from the pdfmake community around this issue, an potential solution would be using this [library](https://github.com/blikblum/pdfmake-utils) which is enables the use of the system fonts. This will reduce your js bundle since there is no need to add the ~900KB of the vfs_fonts.js